# in microsoft graph api for excel how can I search data in workboook

Tags: excel, angular, microsoft-graph-api

I can get all rows in the table using this api call
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives//items//workbook/worksheets/Sheet2/tables/1/rows

But how can I filter or search rows.

for example i want rows where first name = "john"
first name is one of the column in the excel table.

I used filter api.But it just applies filter to the table .It doesn't return the filtered rows..

Comment: where you ever able to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

See the [recent additions](https://dev.office.com/blogs/additions-to-excel-rest-api-on-microsoft-graph) to Excel REST APIs. A new API to return filtered rows is now available.

On the table that you are filtering the data, you can get the underlying range and get its `visibleView`. 
Example: 
GET `tables/{id}/range/visibleView`

You can also access the rows one at a time by `GET /{range-object}/visibleView/rows`

Comment: Hi Sudhi Thanks very much for your reply.So to filter the table I will have to send two calls to Excel rest end point .right?First call to apply the filter and second call to get the visibleview.What if another user applies filter at the same time .will he see his filtered view or my filtered view?

Comment: Two calls are necessary for getting filtered view. Since Excel saves the previous filter, the last filter wins. If you wish to not affect the other user's filter view, you could use a non-persistent session for the interaction. Refer [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/excel) for details on non-persistent session.